# How we can convert a time series data into supervised learning problem?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, feature-extraction, feature-selection

I am preparing a data for machine learning model. I want to deal with time series data as normal supervised learning prediction. Let's say I have a data for car speed and I have several cars models such as

```
+-----+---------+-------------+
| day |  Model  |   Speed     |
+-----+---------+-------------+
|   1 | Bentley | 20.47 km/h  |
|   2 | Bentley | 32.22 km/h  |
|   3 | Bentley | 23.11 km/h  |
|   1 | BMW     | 37.60 km/h  |
|   2 | BMW     | 27.90 km/h  |
|   3 | BMW     | 40.47 km/h  |
```

So I want to deal with several car models in the training so that my machine learning model should predict the speed for Bentley and BMW.

I have converted the data for training like this :

```
+---------+------------+------------+-------------------+
|  Model  |   day_1    |     day_2  |    label == day_3 |
+---------+------------+------------+-------------------+
| Bentley | 20.47 km/h | 32.22 km/h | 23.11 km/h        |
| BMW     | 37.60 km/h | 27.90 km/h | 40.47 km/h        |
+---------+------------+------------+-------------------+
```

Is it a correct approach?

Comment: Could you add a little bit more background information: what is the deployment situation, do you get data for the first two days from a new car manufacturer and want to predict the speed on day 3? How many speed measurements do you have for each car manufacturer? Do you have other variables available?

Comment: @mloning yes I want to predict the speed for the next day, I have day1 and day2 I should predict for day3 . After that , I should predict for day4 using day1,day2,day3 . I have 10 other variables.

Comment: So you have multivariate time series, and you are not willing to use ARIMA, but what exactly do you mean by "normal supervised learning prediction"? There are NN-based solutions such as AR-Net and LSTNet, but what is the purpose of not using traditional approach such as ARIMA?

Comment: check *Multivariate Forecasting* [How to Convert a Time Series to a Supervised Learning Problem in Python](https://machinelearningmastery.com/convert-time-series-supervised-learning-problem-python/)